Jetpack Compose Simple Bottom Navigation
I’m currently working on an Android application using Jetpack Compose and I’m trying to implement a bottom navigation bar.
I have defined a sealed class for my navigation items, each with a route, label, and icon. Here’s what it looks like:
sealed class Navigation(val route: String, val label: String, val icon: Int) {
    data object Home : Navigation("home", "Home", R.drawable.home_ico)
    data object Profile : Navigation("profile", "Profile", R.drawable.person_ico)
    data object Search : Navigation("search", "Search", R.drawable.search_vector)
}

I also have a Main composable function that sets up my NavHost:
@Composable
fun Main(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Navigation.Home.route) {
        composable(Navigation.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(Navigation.Profile.route) {
            ProfileScreen()
        }
        composable(Navigation.Search.route) {
            SearchScreen()
        }
    }
}

And I have a BottomNavigationBar composable function which is supposed to display the bottom navigation bar:
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavHostController, currentItem: MutableIntState) {
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

    val navigationItems = listOf(
        Navigation.Home.route,
        Navigation.Profile.route,
        Navigation.Search.route
    )
    // Im stuck here
}

However, I’m not sure how to proceed with implementing the BottomNavigation in the BottomNavigationBar composable. I want each item in the bottom navigation bar to correspond to a Navigation object, and when an item is clicked, the app should navigate to the corresponding screen.

You should use a Scaffold for that.
@Composable
fun Main(navController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigationBar(navController)
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Navigation.Home.route, modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
            composable(Navigation.Home.route) {
                HomeScreen()
            }
            composable(Navigation.Profile.route) {
                ProfileScreen()
            }
            composable(Navigation.Search.route) {
                SearchScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}   

And then use BottomNavigation:
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

    val navigationItems = listOf(
        Navigation.Home,
        Navigation.Profile,
        Navigation.Search
    )
    BottomNavigation {
      navigationItems.forEach { screen ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
          icon = { Icon(painter = painterResource(screen.icon), contentDescription = stringResource(screen.label)) },
          label = { Text(stringResource(screen.label)) },
          selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
          onClick = {
            navController.navigate(screen.route)
          }
        )
      }
    }
}

More info here.
